# React progress bar with each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

i am pretty new in react. And i want to ask you. Is here any way how to make Progress bar that is loading with each click? I mean. Each click will give me 10% to progress bar until 100% and then it will reset and will start counting again soo i will need to click 10 times to get 100%

1st click 10% second 20% ... etc etc.
Wanna make something like when you get 100% you will get 1 point. (each 10 clicks = 1point (score).

thank you sooo much!

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you have done so far?

Comment: I am just starting. Have nothing now. sorry :/

Comment: Then you need to start doing it. Find a module for [progress bar](https://github.com/react-component/progress) and read the docs. Try making something on your own before asking someone to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for that progress bars. This is what i was looking for :-D my english is maybe too bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not suitable question for StackOverflow but I have free time and interest. Please read [all of this](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

- click changes state (adds 10)
- state determines div width

```js
class ProgressBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      width: 0,
      score: 0
    };    
  }

  render() {
    const style = {
      width: this.state.width + '%'
    };
  
    return (
      <div className="wrapper" onClick={(e) => { this.handleClick(e); }}>
        {'Score: ' + this.state.score} <br />
        {this.state.width + '%'}
        <div className="bar" style={style} />
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  handleClick(e) {
    this.setState(state => {
      if (state.width + 10 === 100) {
        return { width: 0, score: state.score + 1 };
      }
      return { width: state.width + 10 };
    });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ProgressBar />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar {
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
  transition: width 0.3s;
  background: #ec6161;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I just do my own code for progressBar but i will use your! Its more clear and that for that score counter! Thank you soo much :) have a nice day bro!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is:

1. Take a `progress` tag set its state to 10% `this.state = {percent: 10}` initially. [progress tag](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_progress.asp) Pass the necessary bounds
2. Add an `onClick()` handler on a button or the progress bar itself and fire the `this.setState({percent: this.state.percent + 10})` method
3. Pass the `this.state.percent` to the `value` prop of the `progress` tag

Comment: thanks! Going to try this <3